# I didn't understand a detail from the Schrijver et al.'s proof of the Tutte-Berge formula

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, matching-theory

I read the proof of the Tutte-Berge formula from the book "Fundamentals
of Graph Theory" by  Allan Bickle (page 204), but one detail I did not understand.

> For a graph to have a 1-factor, Tutte's condition must hold, since
> each odd component must have some vertex matched to a vertex in $S$.
> More generally, any matching must miss $n-\operatorname{def}(G)$
> vertices, so the size of a maximum matching is at most
> $\frac{1}{2}(n-\operatorname{def}(G))$. Tutte proved the converse of
> the first statement, characterizing graphs with 1-factors. Berge
> extended this result to prove that
> $\alpha^{\prime}(G)=\frac{1}{2}(n-\operatorname{def}(G))$
>
> Theorem $7.20$ (Tutte-Berge Formula-Berge [1958]). If $G$ is a
> multigraph, then
> $\alpha^{\prime}(G)=\frac{1}{2}(n-\operatorname{def}(G))$.
>
> Proof (Schrijver [ [2003] $)$. We have noted that
> $\frac{1}{2}(n-\operatorname{def}(G))$ is an upper bound. We prove the
> reverse inequality by induction on $n$. The case $n=1$ is trivial. We
> can assume that $G$ is connected, as otherwise we can apply induction
> to the components of $G$.
>
> First assume that there exists a vertex $v$ covered by all
> maximum-size matchings. Then
> $\alpha^{\prime}(G-v)=\alpha^{\prime}(G)-1$, and by induction there
> exists a subset $U^{\prime}$ of $V(G)-v$ with
> $$\alpha^{\prime}(G-v)=\frac{1}{2}\left((n-1)+\left|U^{\prime}\right|-o\left(G-v-U^{\prime}\right)\right). $$ Then $U=U^{\prime} \cup\{v\}$ gives equality. So we can assume
> that there is no such $v$. In particular,
> $\alpha^{\prime}(G)<\frac{n}{2}$. We show there is a matching of size
> $\frac{n-1}{2}$, which implies the theorem (with $U=\emptyset$ ).
>
> Indeed suppose to the contrary that each maximum-size matching $M$
> misses at least two distinct vertices $u$ and $v$. Among all such $M,
>  u, v$, choose them such that the distance $d(u, v)$ of $u$ and $v$ in
> $G$ is as small as possible.
>
> If $d(u, v)=1$, then $u$ and $v$ are adjacent, and hence we can
> augment $M$ by $u v$, contradicting the maximality of $|M|$. So $d(u,
>  v) \geq 2$, and hence we can choose an intermediate vertex $t$ on a
> shortest $u-v$ path. By assumption, there exists a maximum-size
> matching $N$ missing $t$.
>
> Consider the component $P$ of the graph induced by $M \cup N$
> containing $t$. As $N$ misses $t, P$ is a path with end $t$. As $M$
> and $N$ are maximum-size matchings, $P$ contains an equal number of
> edges in $M$ as in $N$. Since $M$ misses $u$ and $v, P$ cannot cover
> both $u$ and $v$. So by symmetry we can assume that $P$ misses $u$.
> Exchanging $M$ and $N$ on $P, M$ becomes a maximum-size matching
> missing both $u$ and $t$. Since $d(u, t)<d(u, v)$, this contradicts
> the minimality of $d(u, v)$.

What confused me was the last paragraph of the narrative.

> Consider the component $P$ of the graph induced by $M \cup N$
> containing $t$. As $N$ misses $t, P$ is a path with end $t$.

I'd like to ask that **the component  $P$ being a path can be derived from the fact that $N$ misses $t$**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the graph induced by $M \cup N$, every vertex has degree at most $2$. You should convince yourself that this means that every component of this graph is either a cycle or a path. Also note that $M$ does not miss $t$, since if it did, that would contradict the choice of $u$ and $v$. Since $N$ misses $t$, the degree of $t$ in the graph induced by $M \cup N$ is exactly one. It follows that its component must be a path, and $t$ must be an endpoint of this path.